# mysqli_fetch_array is not returning anything

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have checked my Sql statement in the `phpMyAdmin` and it returns multiple results but when i run it as a php script it doesn't return anything. Can anyone please tell me what mistake i'm making?

```
<?php 
require "conn.php";
/*$sqlQry = $_POST["sqlQry"];*/

$sqlQry = "SELECT bad.id, Name, Address, Latitude, Longitude, AvAge FROM baraddresses bad inner join barlivedata bld on bad.id = bld.id inner join bar_data bdt on bdt.id = bad.id";

$result = mysqli_query($conn ,$sqlQry);

$json = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result , MYSQL_NUM)){
$json[] = array('id' => $row[0], 
        'Name' => $row[1],
        'Address' => $row[2],
        'Latitude'=> $row[3],
        'Longitude' => $row[4],         
        'AvAge' => $row[5]          
            );
}

$jsonstring = json_encode($json);
    echo $jsonstring; 

?>
```

Conn.php

```
<?php

/* This file allows you to connect to a database */


$db_name = "bdata";
$mysql_username = "root";
$mysql_password = "" ;
$server_name = "localhost";
$conn = mysqli_connect($server_name , $mysql_username , $mysql_password , $db_name  );

/*
if($conn){
echo "true";
} 
*/

?>
```

Comment: change to MYSQLI_NUM

Comment: does this return anything when u run on php myadmin?

Comment: Yes it does in phpmyadmin.

Comment: @Gurchani can you please add this `if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { then your while loop}else{echo "No results}`

Comment: No even echoing "No result"

Comment: it suppose to show that atleast, then maybe your query does not run, check error log

Comment: How can i see the error log?

Comment: does your connection file is Conn.php or conn.php ?

Comment: I have tried that but still no result. It just returns empty page instead of any results. same as the one i have from my code.

Comment: @AlivetoDie I get empty page from your code as i tried to run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you code like below and check once:-

***conn.php*** (check file name and correct yourself):-

```
<?php
    //comment these two lines when everything started working fine
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors',1);

    $db_name = "bdata";
    $mysql_username = "root";
    $mysql_password = "" ;
    $server_name = "localhost";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($server_name , $mysql_username , $mysql_password , $db_name  );

    if(!$conn){
      echo "connection error:-".mysqli_connect_error();
    }
?>
```

And other page:-

```
<?php
    //comment these two lines when everything started working fine
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    require "conn.php";

    $sqlQry = "SELECT bad.id, bad.Name, bad.Address, bad.Latitude, bad.Longitude, bad.AvAge FROM baraddresses bad JOIN barlivedata bld on bad.id = bld.id JOIN bar_data bdt on bdt.id = bad.id";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn ,$sqlQry) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    $json = array();
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
       /* Either use this */
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $json[] = array('id'=>$row['id'],'Name'=>$row['Name'],'Address'=>$row['Address'],'Latitude'=>$row['Latitude'],'Longitude'=>$row['Longitude'],'AvAge'=>$row['AvAge']);
        }
        /* Or use this

        $json = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        mysqli_free_result($result); */

        mysqli_close($conn);

        echo "<pre/>";print_r($json);

        $jsonstring = json_encode($json);

        echo $jsonstring; 
    }else{
      die('No record exist');
    }
?>
```

Comment: why not to use simply mysqli_fetch_all, as long as the OP is filling a new array with the same database columns names?

Comment: @hassan  added that

Comment: @Gurchani  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 2):

Change `MYSQL_NUM` to `MYSQLI_NUM`;-

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result , MYSQLI_NUM)){


}
```

Comment: you have enough reputation to put it as a comment

Comment: @Gurchani  do `echo $sqlQry;die();` and copy and paste that query directly to phpmyadmin and check anything returned or not?

Comment: I have pasted it directed in phpmy admin and it does return results there but when i run it in this code it doesnt return anything.

Comment: @Gurchani  can you please add `conn.php` code too in your question

Comment: var_dump($result) and see what its returning

Comment: @ArunKumaresh what makes u think its him?

Comment: Added the conn.php

Comment: Thanks you save my day, I was looking for this code for two days trying to run old script on `php 8` `MYSQLI` were the way to solve all errors